# Theos on Mavericks: symbols not found

Tags: osx-mavericks, symbols, tweak, theos

**Please scroll down, update below**

---

I used this tutorial to get my hands dirty on Theos and jailbreak tweak development:
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started

The question has been posted before ( [Theos for armv7 and arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942087/theos-for-armv7-and-arm64) ), but it hasn't been answered.

To start, I just want to make a console message appear whenever I unlock the device. I followed the tutorial, but had to install `dpkg` via MacPorts to get `ldid` up and running.

Here's my code:

Tweak.xm:

```
%hook SBAwayLockBar

- (void)unlock {
    %orig;
    NSLog( @"SBAwayLockBar.unlock()" );
}

%end
```

makefile:

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = TweakTest01
TweakTest01_FILES = Tweak.xm
TweakTest01_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

after-install::
    install.exec "killall -9 SpringBoard"
```

This happens when I try to either `make` or `make package install`:

```
/tmp/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin/iphone.mk:41: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Making all for tweak TweakTest01...
 Linking tweak TweakTest01...
ld: warning: ignoring file /tmp/theos/lib/libsubstrate.dylib, missing required architecture armv7 in file /tmp/theos/lib/libsubstrate.dylib (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_MSHookMessageEx", referenced from:
      _logosLocalInit() in Tweak.xm.6991e5bc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [obj/TweakTest01.dylib.ba964c90.unsigned] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [TweakTest01.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

I tried a `/usr/bin/xcode-select --install` (as suggested by [Failed to build Saurik's ldid utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776753/failed-to-build-sauriks-ldid-utility)), but that didn't help at all - mainly because I had all Xcode tools already installed.

Any hints?

---

**UPDATE 2014-03-25**

So... it seems like the problem was a space in the path names that I worked in. After renaming the folder from "jailbreak stuff" to "jailbreakstuff", `make` ran fine. But since the tweak I wrote didn't really do anything, I started from scratch.

Here's what I did:

1. Get a theos installer script from https://gist.github.com/tom-go/3342263
2. Edit `install_theos.sh` line 40 to `msdeb="mobilesubstrate_0.9.5001_iphoneos-arm.deb"` (newest version when browsing http://apt.saurik.com/debs/ )
3. I noticed getting `ldid` from the given Dropbox URL resulted in an error because the file that had been downloaded only included some HTML ("You will be redirected..."); so I referred back to http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started#For_Mac_OS_X and executed step #4

   ```
   git clone git://git.saurik.com/ldid.git
   cd ldid
   git submodule update --init
   ./make.sh
   cp -f ./ldid $THEOS/bin/ldid
   ```

Here are my sources:

**Tweak.mm/Tweak.mm (symlink)**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>

%hook SBAwayLockBar

- (void)unlock {
     %orig;
     %log;

    // Call flash on SBScreenFlash => will flash Screen
    [[%c(SBScreenFlash) sharedInstance] flash];
}

%end
```

**makefile**

```
export ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64
export TARGET = iphone:clang:7.1:7.1

include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = TweakTest01
TweakTest01_FILES = Tweak.xm
TweakTest01_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit Foundation

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

after-install::
    install.exec "killall -9 SpringBoard"
```

Here's some console output of `make package` (I replaced "mycompanyname" before posting here):

```
Making all for tweak TweakTest01...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
 Linking tweak TweakTest01...
 Stripping TweakTest01...
 Signing TweakTest01...
Making stage for tweak TweakTest01...
dpkg-deb: Baue Paket »com.mycompanyname.tweaktest01« in »./com.mycompanyname.tweaktest01_0.0.1-9_iphoneos-arm.deb«.
```

Now I transfer the file with iFunBox and install the package by selecting it in iFile. Installation works fine. I respring my device, unlock it... and no flash, no log output. The only thing the (Xcode - Organizer) log shows is

```
SpringBoard[4602] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/TweakTest01.dylib
SpringBoard[4602] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector unlock
```

I tried two different `libsubstrate.dylib` versions

- https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev/blob/master/lib/libsubstrate.dylib
- http://cdn.hbang.ws/dl/libsubstrate_arm64.dylib (renamed to `$THEOS/lib/libsubstrate.dylib`)

but the behaviour is the same. What's next? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whooohooo, I got it! Thanks to #theos on `irc.saurik.com`, I found out that I tried to hook a deprecated header method. Now my Tweak.xm looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>

%hook SBLockScreenViewController

- (void) finishUIUnlockFromSource:(int)arg1 {
    %orig;
    %log;

    NSLog( @"arg1: %d", arg1 );
    [[%c(SBScreenFlash) sharedInstance] flash];

}

%end
```

Just for reference:

http://developer.limneos.net/?framework=SpringBoard&header=SBLockScreenViewControllerBase.h
https://github.com/thomasfinch/iOS-7-SpringBoard-Headers

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your `libsubstrate.dylib` (in theos/lib/), which doesn't seem to contain an armv7 slice. Try downloading a new one and replace yours (maybe [this one](http://cdn.hbang.ws/dl/libsubstrate_arm64.dylib) would work)